# Should I use super() every time I call parent function or only inside overridden functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we override parent class's method, we can use `super()` to avoid mention of parent class's name - that's clear.

But what about case, when we just use in subclass some function defined in parent class? What is preferable way: to use `super().parent_method()` or `self.parent_method()`? Or there's no difference?

```
class A:
    def test1(self):
        pass

    def test_a(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def test1(self):
        super().test1()  # That's clear.

    def test_b(self):
        # Which option is better, when I want to use parent's func here?
        # 1) super().test_a()
        # 2) self.test_a()
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you will want to use `self.test_a()` to call an inherited method. However, in some rare situations you might want to use `super().test_a()` even though it seems to do the same thing. They're not equivalent, even though they have the same behavior in your example.

To explore the differences, lets make two versions of your `B` class, one with each kind of call, then make two `C` classes that further extend the `B` classes and override `test_a`:

```
class A(object):
    def test_a(self):
        return "A"

class B1(A):
    def test_b(self):
        return self.test_a() + "B"

class B2(A):
    def test_b(self):
        return super().test_a() + "B"

class C1(B1):
    def test_a(self):
        return "C"

class C2(B2):
    def test_a(self):
        return "C"
```

When you call the `test_b()` method on `C1` and `C2` instances you'll get different results, even though `B1` and `B2` behave the same:

```
>>> B1().test_b()
'AB'
>>> B2().test_b()
'AB'
>>> C1().test_b()
'CB'
>>> C2().test_b()
'AB'
```

This is because the `super()` call in `B2.test_b` tells Python that you want to skip the version of `test_a` in any more derived class and always call an implementation from a parent class. (Actually, I suppose it could be a sibling class in a multiple inheritance situation, but that's getting even more obscure.)

Like I said at the top, you usually want to allow a more-derived class like the `C`s to override the behavior of the inherited methods you're calling in your less-derived class. That means that most of the time using `self.whatever` is the way to go. You only need to use `super` when you're doing something fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Since `B` *is an* `A`, it has a member `test_a`. So you call it as

```
self.test_a()
```

`B` does *not* overwrite `A.test_a` so there is no need to use `super()` to call it.

Since `B` *overwrites*  `A.test1`, you must explicitly name the method you want to call.

```
self.test1()
```

will call `B.test1`, while

```
super().test1()
```

will call `A.test1`.

Answer (score 1):

> If we override parent class's method, we can use super() to avoid
>   mention of parent class's name - that's clear.

actually `super()` is not syntactic sugar, its purpose is to invoke parent implementation of a certain method.
You have to use `super()` when you want to **override** a parent method, you don't have to use `super()` when instead you want to **overwrite** a method. The difference is that in the first case you want to add extra behavior (aka code execution) before or after the original implementation, in the second you want a completely different implementation.
You can't use `self.method_name()` in an override, the result will be a recursion error! (`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`)

Example:

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print('A.m implementation')

class B(A):
     def m(self):
        super().m()
        print('B.m implementation')

class C(A):
     def m(self):
        print('C.m implementation')

class D(A):
    def m(self):
        self.m()


a = A()
a.m()

b = B()
b.m()

c = C()
c.m()

d = D()
d.m()
```

Given a base class `A`, with a method `m`, `B` extends `A` by overriding `m`, `C` extends `A` by overwriting `m`, and `D` generates an error!

**EDIT:**

I just realized that you actually have 2 different methods (`test_a` and `test_b`). My answer is still valid, but regarding your specific scenario:

you should use `self.test_a()` unless you override/overwrite that method in your class B and you want to execute the original implementation... so we can say that calling `super().test_a()` or `self.test_a()` it's the same given that you'll never override/overwrite the original `test_a()` in your subclasses... however is a nonsense to use `super()` if not for an override/overwrite

Comment: Nor is @germn overriding `test_a()` nor overwriting it. How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: Now I see an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly both the ways `super().test_a()` and `self.test_a()` will result in execution of method `test_a()`.

Since `Class B` does not override or overwrite `test_a()` I think use of `self.test_a()` will be much efficient as self is a mere reference to the current object which is there in memory.

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), `super()` results in creation of proxy object which contains other methods also. Owing to this reason I feel `self` will be the correct approach in your case.